# Visual Studio Online source path

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops

How do I programmatically determine the path of my source code when running unit tests in Visual Studio Online's hosted build infrastructure.

Why do I want to know this? I want an integration test to run `redis-server.exe` from the `Redis-64` NuGet package so that it can run tests that use Redis.

---

FWIW, here are the environment variables from the Visual Studio Online build server:

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
COMPUTERNAME=BUILD-0012
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
GTK_BASEPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\
VSSDK140Install=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VSSDK\
VSSDK120Install=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\
PROCESSOR_REVISION=2d07
VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
TMP=C:\Users\BUILDG~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TEMP=C:\Users\BUILDG~1\AppData\Local\Temp
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
ANDROID_HOME=C:\java\androidsdk\android-sdk
M2_HOME=C:\java\maven\apache-maven-3.2.2
JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25
USERDOMAIN=BUILD-0012
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
EnableNuGetPackageRestore=True
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
VSSDK110Install=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\buildguest
VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
APPDATA=C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Roaming
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ANT_HOME=C:\java\ant\apache-ant-1.9.4
WIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\
XNAGSShared=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\XNA\
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
USERNAME=buildguest
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
OS=Windows_NT
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\java\androidsdk\android-ndk-r10d
SystemDrive=C:
windir=C:\Windows
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
```

Answer (score 1):

`TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` works as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx#env_vars) in pre-post test scripts.
They are not available in the VSTestRunner activity.

So you should prepare your application using a pre-test script, where you can grab stuff from known build places.

**NOTE**
The environment variables are available only with later build templates, like TfvcTemplate.12.xaml and GitTemplate.12.xaml. The DefaultTemplate.11.xaml shows only TF_BUILD.

Comment: I agree with the *should* part. I tried that. No dice. There are no TF environment variables. Perhaps because they support building from both TFS and Git sources they aren't actually using Team Build.

Comment: Just checked. It works, _but_ must use the new build templates ending with 12, i.e. GitTemplate.12.xaml or TfvcTemplate.12.xaml.

Comment: I'm using TfvcTemplate.12.xaml, which gives the environment variables shown in the question. Perhaps only the Git template works?

Comment: Weird. As I said, I tested using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml and see the variables while compiling (in the MSBuild project) and from the pre-post-/scripts. The DefaultTemplate.11.xaml shows only `TF_BUILD`.

Note that `TF_*` variables are set at the _process_ level, except for `TF_BUILD` that is defined at _machine_ level. Processes must bu children of the build agent to get the vars.

Comment: Perhaps there are different variables for building vs. test execution. To get a dump of the test execution variables, I put the following code in one of my unit tests: `throw new InvalidOperationException("Environment variables:\n" + string.Join("\n", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>().Select(e => e.Key + "=" + e.Value)));`.

Comment: You are correct. The variables are available during the build but not at the test runner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79017/discussion-between-giulio-vian-and-edward-brey).

Answer (score 0):

Type `C:\a\src` into your source code. At least the path is always the same, but I hope there's a better answer.